# Unable to push changes to a public repo where Im added as 'collaborator'

Tags: git, github

Hello I cloned a public repository owned by vikramcvk (git username).
added a new file in the local cloned directory
Wanted to push this new file to the public repository owned by vikramcvk where im added as collaborator(dw-marcy is my git username).

Sequence of commands and the error

```
$ git clone https://github.com/vikramcvk/background-generator.git/
$ cd background-generator

(background-generator)$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean

(background-generator)$ git push
Username for 'https://github.com':dw-marcy
Password for 'https://dw-marcy@github.com': <PAT created by my>

remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/vikramcvk/background-generator.git/'

(background-generator)$
```

Created a PAT and was entering the username and PAT as the password .. but its giving the above error.

Also added my github username(dw-marcy) was added as collaborator by vikramcvk in his github account.

Please help me out.

Comment: you can't use a pat in that context: see: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls

Answer (score 0):

As illustrated by [this article](https://goodguydaniel.com/blog/how-to-fix-github-password-authentication), a possible reason you would see "upport for password authentication was removed ..." when entering a PAT is if that PAT has expired.

Double-check the [scope](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps) and expiration of your current PAT.
Try and create a new one, to see if the issue persists.
Make sure the PAT does follow the [new (2021) format](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-03-31-authentication-token-format-updates-are-generally-available/).

> `ghp_...` for Personal Access Tokens